# Removing Redundancies From a Path

Tags: java, path

From Java Tutorial:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html

> The following examples both include redundancies:

```
/home/./joe/foo
/home/sally/../joe/foo
```

> The normalize method removes any redundant elements, which includes
>   any "." or "directory/.." occurrences. Both of the preceding examples
>   normalize to:

```
 /home/joe/foo
```

Where do the two "redundant" paths point to and how can they be "normalized" like this?

Comment: Do you not understand what `.` and `..` mean?

Comment: I just understand that is the current directory and the parent directory, I don't understand how they work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, `.` means the current directory and `..` means up a directory.  In

```
/home/./joe/foo
```

`.` points to /home because the current directory is "home" in that context.  As another example, these are the same

```
/foo/././././.
/foo
```

In

```
/home/sally/../joe/foo
```

The /sally/.. is redundant.  It's like saying, "go into this directory, then take a step back".  It's the same as this:

```
/home/joe/foo
```

Answer (score 1):

The name "path" is more literal than you might think.  If you think of the filesystem as a tree rooted at `/`, then each path element represents a choice as you walk down, away from the root.  `/home/joe/foo` means

1. Start at the root
2. Within the root go to `home`
3. Then within `home` go to `joe`
4. Then within `joe` go to `foo`

The path `/home/sally/../joe/foo` means

1. Start at the root
2. Within the root go to `home`
3. Then within `home` go to `sally`
4. Then go back up a level (the `..`) up to `home` again
5. Then within `home` go to `joe`
6. Then within `joe` go to `foo`

So you can see that the two paths get you to the same place.

A single dot means *"stay in the same place"* so path elements consisting of `.` can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can split path wrt "/" and process after that.

```
String[] arr = path.split("/");
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i].equals("."))
        arr[i] = "";
    else if(arr[i].equals("..")){
        boolean changed = false;int j = i - 1;
        while(arr[j].equals(""))
            j--;
        if(j >= 0)
            arr[j] = "";
    }
}
```

This will delete redundant elements, then combine array again.